# lack of /bin/bash shell for user causes "login incorrect" for ftp with filezilla

Tags: server, bash, ftp, filezilla

So I set up an Ubuntu Server 16.04 AWS micro EC2 instance for my students to upload files to. They could login via ssh with putty but when using ftp with Filezilla their passwords were rejected:

```
Status: Connecting to ##.##.##.##:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER test1
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
Status: Disconnected from server
```

You could however log in with sftp as well:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>sftp test4@##.##.##.##
test4@##.##.##.##'s password:
Connected to test4@##.##.##.##.
sftp> quit
```

I fixed this by doing

```
usermod -shell /bin/bash username
```

for all their usernames. However, I was wondering why this happened. Is it because the lack of a bash shell causes strange characters to appear when Filezilla logs in which gets entered with their password?
Thanks.

Comment: What FTP server is it? if `vsftpd`, this may be relevant: [Users with /bin/false shell to login on vsftpd](https://linux-tips.com/t/users-with-bin-false-shell-to-login-on-vsftpd/200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steeldriver answered this one but I can't figure out how to vote him up or mark his comment as the answer (maybe I don't have the reputation) https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver The answer is here: https://linux-tips.com/t/users-with-bin-false-shell-to-login-on-vsftpd/200